# Falla en cursor en VISUAL STUDIO CODE

Tags: vscode, cursor

Tengo un error al tipear en Visual Studio Code.  Se engrosa el cursor y no me deja escribir/editar el codigo.  Ya desinstale y volvi a instalar.  Por supuesto presiono insert y se soluciona, pero al muy poco tiempo, vuelve a estar igual.  Una incomodidad ya que cada vez q tengo que hacer algo, tengo que presionar insert primero.  Probe tambien desde la configuracion del cursor, pero no se soluciona.
Probe las soluciones que ofrecian en las respuestas a otra persona que genero esta consulta pero no me resultaron.
Espero se entienda mi duda.
Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porfavor ayuda también tengo este mismo problema y es desesperante te tira todo el trabajo pero me pasa aun sin tener la extension de Vim instalada, me sucede en cualquier Linux en cuanto comienzo a usar VSCode alguna otra solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es un fallo, el `-- NORMAL --` que se ve en la barra inferior sugiere que tienes habilitada la extensión Vim. Si no te gusta puedes desactivarla o desinstalarla desde el menu de extensionses.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]